# Can't get to link so image using constants

Tags: php, mysql

Why can I find my image when I use this ?

```
defined("PROD_IMAGES") ? null : 
define("PROD_IMAGES", realpath(dirname(__DIR__) .  "/public/images/"));
$product_image = PROD_IMAGES . $image;   
<img src="<?php echo PROD_IMAGES; ?>" alt="">
```

Comment: Where are you looking for your file?

Comment: in the site-root/public/images

Comment: I see this in inspect element  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/_MISC/online_shop_2/public/images/image_4.jpg

Comment: Shouldn't you use `$product_image` instead of `PROD_IMAGES` in your `img` `src`?

Comment: I'm trying to have a CONSTANT define the PATH first so that I can access the images folder from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

*absolute path*:

```
 <img src="http://www.yourDomain.com/images/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="">
```

Or *relative to website root*:

```
 <img src="/images/<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="">
```